# Home Page - displaying the wrong one

Tags: home, magento2.2.6

I've gone around and around with this issue and moved no further. Just setting up a new store and if I go to https://wisevape.co.uk I get on page (not one that I can seem to edit) but if I go to https://wisevape.co.uk/home then I get my genuine home page that I can amend etc.

I've been playing with Stores/Config/General/Web and I can't make it go to the right place (I can't figure out where the other page is coming from either).

I'm new to Magento so it is probably something I'm missing. I'm running 2.2.6 CE and help on this would be gratefully received!

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: check  configuration by store / site view. your default settings would be overriding the other ones you are checking.

Comment: I've put the site in to single store mode to try and resolve the issue so there shouldn't be multiples trying to conflict or do you mean something else?

Comment: did you flushed cache after making the changes ? because this seems configuration issue on different stores. Even you have single store "Default Config" and "Main site" configuration could be different.

Comment: I did indeed flush the cache after every change. Okay how do I amend the Default Config and Main site config as you suggest? Sorry I'm getting up to speed with Magento still

Comment: while you go to Stores->Configuration on top there would be drop down "Store View" change store view from there and change "Home Page"

Comment: That drop down has gone since I put the install in to single store mode but while it was in multi store mode I did try amending the settings in every available level